# I need help converting an iterative function into a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

Posting Homework is probably not that well recieved around here, but i'm seriously stuck.

My task, is to convert a String which contains a Tree in Newick-Format, into its bipartitions and I need to solve the problem recursivly.
E.g.:

```
tree = "((1,2),((3,((4,5),(6,7))),(8,9)))"
read_tree(tree)
```

[image]
Each branch of the tree above is represented by one of the bipartitions below.

Output:

```
{{1},{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}
{{2},{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}
{{4},{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}
{{5},{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}}
{{6},{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9}}
{{7},{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9}}
{{4, 5},{1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9}}
{{6, 7},{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9}}
{{3},{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}
{{4, 5, 6, 7},{1, 2, 3, 8, 9}}
{{8},{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9}}
{{9},{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}
{{3, 4, 5, 6, 7},{8, 1, 2, 9}}
{{8, 9},{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}}
{{1, 2},{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}}
{{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},{1, 2}}
```

For the first few hours, I tried various ideas. Each one so bad, I can't even explain what I did.
But then i thougt of something I've read some time ago.
That is: Every iterative Function can be replaced with an recursive Function.

So I came up with this:

```
def read_tree(newick):
    leaf_set = set()
    index = 0
    for leaf in newick:
        if not leaf == "(" and not leaf == ")" and not leaf == ",":
            leaf_set.add(int(leaf))
    for e in newick:
        if e == ")":
            r_nodes = set()
            l_nodes = set()
            brace_counter = 0
            i_tmp = index-1
            add_ln = False
            add_nodes = True
            while add_nodes:
                if newick[i_tmp] == ")":
                    brace_counter += 1
                if newick[i_tmp] == "(":
                    brace_counter -= 1
                if newick[i_tmp] == "," and brace_counter == 0:
                    add_ln = True
                if not add_ln:
                    if not newick[i_tmp] == "(" 
                    and not newick[i_tmp] == ")" 
                    and not newick[i_tmp] == ",":
                        r_nodes.add(int(newick[i_tmp]))
                if add_ln:
                    if not newick[i_tmp] == "(" 
                    and not newick[i_tmp] == ")" 
                    and not newick[i_tmp] == ",":
                        l_nodes.add(int(newick[i_tmp]))
                if brace_counter == -1 and len(l_nodes) > 0:
                    add_nodes = False
                i_tmp -= 1
            print("{", end="")
            print(l_nodes, end=",")
            print(leaf_set.difference(l_nodes), end="}\n{")
            print(r_nodes, end=",")
            print(leaf_set.difference(r_nodes), end="}\n")
        index += 1
```

This function might do the job, but in order to pass, code I'm going to submit must solve this problem via recursion.

And now I'm stuck again, cause I can't wrap my head around, on how to make this recusrive.

I'm not necesserily asking for solutions. But some hints on how to tackle this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Interesting. Could you please explain, in your own words, what are the bipartitions of a tree?

Comment: Also it would help if you could add a drawing of the tree, in addition to its Newick-format representation.

Comment: Also please explain more specifically what it is that you need help with. It kind of looks like you successfully solved the problem with an iterative function, but now you want help converting it into a recursive function? I say "it kind of looks" because it's not clear at all whether you have solved the problem or not. Please make it clearer.

Comment: A bipartition is a list of every single branch inside of the tree. So a tree is definetly defined by its bipartition

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. A first step that will help you is to separate the logic of the algorithm from the displays. I suggest rewriting your code so that your function doesn't use `print()` at all, but instead returns the list using keyword `return`.

Answer (score 0):

In case it’s still useful.

```
newick="((1,2),((3,((4,5),(6,7))),(8,9)))"
bipart=list()
leaf_set=set()

def getLeafs():
    for leaf in newick:
            if not leaf == "(" and not leaf == ")" and not leaf == ",":
                leaf_set.add(leaf)
                
def buildBiparts(index):
    if index >= len(newick):
        return 
    
    if newick[index] in leaf_set:
         str=newick[index]
         index+=2
         if newick[index] in leaf_set:
             str+=','+newick[index]
         bipart.append(str)
         
    index+=1
    buildBiparts(index)
            
        
getLeafs()
buildBiparts(0)
print(bipart)
```

Print result:

```
['1,2', '3', '4,5', '6,7', '8,9']
```

Comment: I suggest making `bipart` a return value of the function, rather than a global variable which is silently modified.